# Return type differs in implementation for objective C protocols

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I have a protocol that has a method returning `NSArray*`.
    In the implementation I had made the return type of that method to be `NSView*`

I see this is happening only in case of Objective C class pointers and not in other cases like returning `void` vs returning `int`.

I would expect a complier warning at the minimum but the compilation happens just fine.

```
@protocol prot <NSObject>

-(NSArray*)array;

@end
@interface impl : NSObject<prot>

@end

@implementation impl

//Should return NSArray. Returns NSView instead
- (NSView *)array
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you post protocol declaration as well here. just wanted to see protocol declaration.

Comment: @ShaikRiyaz: Sorry I thought i did. Edited OP to show that now.

Comment: it's fine. let me check and get back to you ..

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

`impl` should be `Implementation` since class names are written in upper camel case and abbreviations are bad(TM). Moreover, `Class` is a class pointer, `NSView*` and `NSArray*` are instance pointers.

To your Q, even I'm a bit tired of this discussion (dynamic vs. static typing, early vs. late binding):

A: Why should the compiler warn? Both are instance pointers and maybe the messages sent to the object are supported by both. The compiler does not care about binding, it is done at runtime.

B: But this is very unsafe!

A: Did you ever ship code with such an error?

B: No. But it is unsafe by theory.

A: Yes, that's true for alle theories that ship code without running it at least one time.

B: But you have to admit, that this is more unsafe than type checking at compile time.

A: Yes, theoretically that's true.

B: So why do you support it?

A: Because there are many situations in which dynamic typing has advantages. I. e. it is very easy to write generic code without having templates. (Even sometimes they are called generics, they are still silly templates.) It is very easy to give around responsibility, what needs contra-conceptual extensions in other languages (signals & slots in C++, delegates in C#, …) It is very easy to create stand-in objects for lowering memory pressure. It is very easy to write an ORIM. Shall I continue?

B: Yes

A: Is is that flexible that you can write a whole AOP framework within that language. It is that flexible that you can write a prototype based framework within that language.

However, sometimes it is easy to detect for the compiler that something makes no sense at all. And sometimes the compiler warns about that. But in many cases the compiler is not more intelligent than the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that it should generate a warning, but it doesn't. Part of the issue is that all ObjC objects are `id` at runtime, which is why you're seeing different behavior for `int` (which isn't `id`). But that's not really an excuse. It's a limitation of the compiler. There are numerous places where it doesn't do a good job of distinguishing between ObjC object types. ObjC objects are duck-typed, so as long as they respond to the right messages "they work."

Sometimes this is a benefit; for example, `NSArray` is actually a class cluster, and there are several (private) types that pretend to be `NSArray` by just implementing the same interface. That's something that is easy in ObjC, but hard in Swift. Still no excuse, since it would be easy to get that benefit without this frustrating lack of a compiler warning, but it gets back to how ObjC thinks about class types.

This limitation is fixed in Swift, and another benefit of moving over, but that doesn't really help you, I know.